# Variable assignment in GAS assembly

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86, gnu-assembler

I am working through Jack Crenshaw's "Let's Build A Compiler." I am translating his Motorola 680x0 instructions into x86 GAS syntax.

During variable assignment, the desired semantics are to create a reference to a variable by using PC-relative addressing (at least that's what Crenshaw is going for). The variable can be accessed in Motorola syntax by:

MOVE x(PC), D0

where x is the variable name.

Here is what the actual procedure looks like for an assignment (in Pascal):

```
procedure Assignment;
var Name: char;
begin
   Name := GetName;
   Match('=');
   Expression;
   EmitLn('LEA ' + Name + '(PC),A0');
   EmitLn('MOVE D0,(A0)')
end;
```

Trying to mimic the same syntax in GAS assembly results in a junk expression error. Hopefully this question isn't too naive, but I've been searching for several days now and don't see an obvious solution.

How do I accomplish this with GAS syntax for an x86 processor on Linux (i386)? I'm looking for the simplest means to accomplish variable assignment. I'm using `as` and `ld` for my assembler and compiler, respectively.

Here's a link to where I am currently, chapter 3 in Crenshaw:

http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/tutor3.txt

Comment: Do you need it to use PC-relative addressing? If not, it seems like a `'movl %eax,' + Name` would do (without having read Crenshaw's book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86-32 doesn't have PC-relative addressing, but x86-64 does.
In any case, on x86 you don't need to go through a register, you can use a symbol directly in the `MOV`. As such, the simplest way to write that would be:  `MOV source_register, variable_name`.
If you do want to mimic the original code more closely, you can use `LEA` like this:

```
LEA variable-name, temp_register
MOV source_register, (temp_register)
```

Comment: I think this approach requires that the variable is declared first. It doesn't appear that Crenshaw declares anything. Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the original question.

Comment: It doesn't have to be declared *first*, but it does need to be eventually defined somewhere, with storage allocation.

Comment: Actually, that is helpful, could the declaration be inline, or does it need to be in .data or .bss sections?

Comment: It can be inline in `.text`, but code sections are typically read-only. It's easy to allocate a variable using the `.lcomm` directive which will place it in `.bss` automatically. Otherwise you can use `.previous` or `.pushsection`/`.popsection`.